# Definition of hollow matrix

Tags: matrices, definition

Can we call a symmetric matrix with

1. diagonal entries all zero and
2. off-diagonal entries greater than or equal to zero,

a **hollow matrix**?

Another way around: Can a hollow matrix have off-diagonal entries equal to zero (at least one entry)? Or, is that matrix called in a different way?

For example, are both these two matrices, hollow matrices?

$$\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 5 & 0 & 2 \\
5 & 0 & 6 & 1 \\
0 & 6 & 0 & 3 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 0
\end{vmatrix}, \qquad 
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 5 & 1 & 2 \\
5 & 0 & 6 & 1 \\
1 & 6 & 0 & 3 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 0
\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: Surely, a symmetric and entrywise nonnegative matrix with a zero diagonal is surely a hollow matrix, but by definition, a hollow matrix is merely a square matrix with a zero diagonal. Symmetry and entrywise non-negativity are not required. The definition also applies to other fields than $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Symmetric matrices have clear definitions, namely $A=A^T$. You can determine if your matrix is symmetric if it satisfies this criteria.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user1551....therefore, if "Symmetry and entrywise non-negativity are not required", if I have one (or a few) off-diagonal entry that is zero, like in the left matrix, can I still call it as a hollow matrix?

Comment: Thanks a lot @CroCo! :-)

Comment: Yes. The values of the off-diagonal entries are irrelevant in the definition of hollow matrix. As long as the matrix is a square one and it has a zero diagonal, it is a hollow matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user1551! If you want to put your comments into an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the two matrices in your question are hollow. However, the definition of a hollow matrix only requires the matrix to be a square one with a zero diagonal. This definition applies to square matrices over any field. It does not require symmetry or entrywise non-negativity. In fact, the values of the off-diagonal entries or the structure of the off-diagonal part are completely irrelevant. As long as the matrix is square and all of its main diagonal elements are zero, it can be called a hollow matrix.